# Troubleshooting Legacy Hardware and Software Issues on MS-DOS and Windows 3.11

Tags: hardware, ms-dos, windows-3.x, scsi, isa

I have an old PC with the following hardware components:

Motherboard: AMI TITAN II EISA rev.D
RAM: 48MB of 4 SIMM
CPU: 154C Pentium (tm)
BIOS: 711011596
HDD1: SCSI controller adapter through PCI (PCI)
GPU: VGA MIRO 40SV ergo.(PCI)\
MATROX-Board: 640 | 1280 (ISA)\ (If you have a manual of this board in English, please do share to me)
Controller: Logitech Mouse (Serial 9pin)
Network card: unknown but it has ETHERNET RJ45 / COAX/ THICK LAN (ISA)

This machine hasn't been used for around 14 years, but we now need to make it work because it's connected to an Emission Microscope that requires a proprietary software for operation. Unfortunately, we no longer have the installation diskette for the software, so reinstalling Windows is not an option.

Here are the issues I'm facing:

**CMOS RTC Battery Replacement**: The CMOS RTC battery was dead, and replacing it wiped the NVRAM memory. I need guidance on how to reconfigure the BIOS settings properly, considering the hardware components.

**MATROX-Board Configuration**: After attempting to use the EISA Configuration Utility to configure the MATROX board, the screen went blank with 8 beeps from AMI. This suggests a possible conflict in RAM allocation. How can I resolve this issue and properly configure the MATROX board?

**MIRO GPU Driver Issue**: After installing the MIRO GPU driver, my "main.grp" file disappeared, and the mouse stopped working. Unable to recreate group because the file is invalid or corrupted. How can I troubleshoot and fix these problems related to the GPU driver?

**Backup Clone HDD Error**: I have a backup clone HDD, but when I swap it in, DOS shows an error saying "command.com" is incorrect. What steps should I take to address this issue?

Additionally, I'm considering connecting the hard drive to a modern computer to explore possible solutions. What adapters or methods should I use to connect the legacy hard drive to a modern system and address these issues?

I appreciate any insights and advice on how to tackle these problems and get this old PC up and running with the necessary configuration for the Emission Microscope software.

Comment: I'm assuming you have custom cards in this machine, and they will definitely have IRQ's and IO addresses that need to be set in the bios as excluded. with a little luck, you might find these labled on the cards.

Comment: to use the clone HDD, I'd simply re-clone, and then re-install msdos to the re-cloned HDD using the original system. so the boot sector's get written to the right place

Comment: Hello camelcc. You're correct. they are proprietary and indeed have to address IRQ's and IO. Also the miro card actually for the miro crt monitor which project from the microscope. The computer + joystick + second monitor, they are only for controlling the movement inside the scope and capture image. Somehow, i can't navigate  through norton backup to reclone it. I need the mouse to work to reclone. And there is no label on the cards, the card has no manual. I don't know why in 1992 they don't  include something like that in a unit that price.

Comment: Well, it was probably considered a service item at the time, and re-running the eisa setup has likely made things more difficult. is this windows 3.0 or 3.1 ?

Comment: If you have configured the matrox board onto an io conflict, I see little option but to remove the other cards to get the card to get the eisa config to run, the trouble is this is going to be a lot of guessing. I'd look on the cards very carefully, often the jumpers are labled. If not, id try and find any .ini files that might give a clue. As far as re-cloning is concerned, one can simply re-install dos to a new (used) drive, and then copy the files across. Should work for all versions of windows 3.x. The mouse not working is indicating IRQ conflict on the serial port

Comment: to connect the scsi hard disk to a modern computer, you will need a scsi card. SCSI cards and devices are completely backwards compatible with each other, including 68 pin 50 pin so long as adapters are used. I would not attempt to use your only copy of the software in a machine with a likely IRQ conflict, as an IRQ conflict can corrupt the hard disk

Comment: I would also try some long shot searches for another installation of the same make and/or model of microscope. There is a small possibility that there was more than one model and there might be common features.

 I would look for research papers that call up the same make and possibly the same model then try to contact the institutions and possibly researchers.

Same goes for a patent search. Sometimes equipment includes patent numbers and that may offer a clue.

Did the equipment require alignment to traceable standards. If so  there might be old alignment reports.

Maintenance techs?

Comment: it's running Windows for Workgroups 3.11. Unfortunately, this is proprietary software. And which .ini file should I look at? I have only two drives, one installed and one is backup. I don't have access to a 3rd drive to re-install dos. Is there any work around maybe pulling DOS from the backup drive and paste that in the old drive?

Comment: So a new problem arise, my current install drive only show half of the capacity. I'm not sure if this issues cause my the SCSI config conflict with something else. But the goal right now is to get the mouse working. Lastly, do I need to physically remove all cards and peripherals when config to avoid conflict?

Comment: @CluelessENGR you need to get another drive or 2, if you actually care about this. Stuff about mouse conflicts is telling me IRQ conflicts, and if this is with the scsi controller, there is a very high probability of completely corrupting the disk. Note win3.11 is limited to a 2GB partition, being the limit of FAT16. Dos generally needs to be written with the machine you plan on booting with it. you should get away with re-installing dos to the disk,